# Does SonarLint have the custom dictionary feature like the FxCop?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

As you know, the FxCop tool allows us to input custom dictionary in the .xml file  for ignoring the casing exception. Does SonarLint also support us to do the same?

Example: We have the names as below:

1. SPVerion
2. SPVersionType
3. SPName
4. ChangedSP
5. ...

These names contain the string "SP" and violate the S100 rule of SonarLint. Can we input a custom dictionary "SP" so that SonarLint will ignore checking for these names?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately we do not support custom dictionaries yet. We did not have a ticket for that, so I created one: [Custom Dictionaries for S100](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-858). It is not easy to implement, but I hope that we could squeeze it in our plans for the upcoming months.

Comment: Thank for your supports in the future. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Ticket is unavailable behind a login. After four years there's still no custom dictionary, giving spurious, unavoidable warnings.

Comment: @Boggin, please send your feedback through the official support channels of SonarSource. I don't work there anymore and I cannot help with the escalation of this ticket.